# Find all parent nodes of a node in a tree

Tags: python, graph

I am creating a tree in python, and I had a method to find a path from the parent to the root node of the tree.  That is as follows:

```
def get_sub_net(self, index):
    node = self.nodes[index]
    sub_net = []
    sub_net.append(node)
    while node.parent is not None:
        node = node.parent
        sub_net.append(node)
    return sub_net[::-1]
```

Now I am trying to allow for each node to have multiple parents, and I am running into trouble.

```
def sub_net(self, index):
    node = self.nodes[index]
    sub_net = []
    if node.parents == None:
        return sub_net
    else:
        sub_net += node.parents
        for i in node.parents:
            while i is not None:
                sub_net += i.parents
                node = i
                break
    return sub_net[::-1]
```

@Noreddine-Kessa pointed out that this would be a graph, and not a tree, which is correct.  However, I also solved my own problem, the solution I used i

```
def recursive_sub_net(self, node):
    sub_net = []
    sub_net.append(node)

    if node.parents is not None:
        for i in node.parents:
            sub_net += self.recursive_sub_net(i)

    return sub_net
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, every node in a tree has a single parent (and can have many ancestors), if you need to use a network of nodes (not tree) then you should use a graph.